# Stop console from closing that's called from another program

Tags: command-line

There's a program I'm running that has information outputted to a console window, and I'm pretty sure it's displaying errors but I cannot see them because it closes. Even if I run the program from the console, it doesn't matter because it's a GUI. Is it even possible to stop the window from closing?

Comment: run it under a debugger and break on the window closing message...

Comment: I didn't make the program myself... I'm saying someone else's program is a GUI that creates a console window and it closes before I can read the errors.

Comment: still my advice stands: you can attach a debugger to it and stop the program before it ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the console window is visible long enough, you could have a separate program (which you would have to write) call [AttachConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to attach to the GUI program's console. Your separate program would have to be a GUI program or detach from its own console before attaching to the GUI program's console.

Your program could then use a [console control handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to intercept the close call. You could then scrape the console screen buffer and save the data. Or maybe even delay the console closing.

That's the basic idea. It's been a while since I played with attaching consoles, so there are probably some details that I've forgotten. Still, it seems like it should work.